# Can you create new classes with different names at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, mvvm, instance

```
    public void AddClothesCollection()
    {
        NewClothesClass newClothesClass1 = new NewClothesClass(newClothes,"");
        Collections.Add(newClothesClass);
    }
```

When I run my code this Method gets fired, which creates a new instance of the class `NewClothesClass1`. This method can get fired multiple times at runtime creating multiple different instances.

Is there any way I can change the name of the class instance when they click it again so it will create a new instance, and so I can go back to another instance of the `NewClothesClass` and add something to it at a later date?

Comment: No, it creates a new instance of `NewClothesClass`. You currently appear to be confused between objects, variables and classes... which makes it very hard to help you, unfortunately.

Comment: @JonSkeet So it is not possible to retrieve an instance of a class if others have been made?

Comment: Well you can store it in a map, e.g. `Dictionary<string, NewClothesClass>` - but it's important to understand that the *object* doesn't have a name in itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks never much, I'm going to have a look into `Dictionarys`. Do you have any example code you could supply?

Comment: There are *lots* of examples in documents all over the web. I suggest you read a book with a chapter describing the various .NET collections so you get a broader overview than just a single class.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the information, I will take alook at some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the name of an variable is a temporary thing, and the same instance can have multiple names at any one time.

What you need to do it give your instance of `NewClothesClass` a name in the constructor, which you can query for later. For example:

```
NewClothesClass x = new NewClothesClass(newClothes,"shirt")
NewClothesClass y = new NewClothesClass(newClothes,"trousers")

Collections.Add(x);
Collections.Add(y);
```

Also, don't put the word **Class** in the name of a class!

Comment: Now I'm totally confused, I always thought when you did `= new NewClothesClass()` it created a new instance of that class?

Comment: @Ben - it does, but in your question you ask about change the name of a "class instance" which is an object. objects don't have permanent names, so you have to add some naming logic to your class in order for you to search for it by name.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand, I'll have to find away around it, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Ben - yes, have your class store a name for each instance, and then search your collection for this name whenever you need to look for something.

Comment: I can create instances with new names and add them to a collection, but how can I do this at runtime?

Comment: @Ben - look at my example. I pass in the name to the class constructor. Whatever name you wanted to use is what you should pass in.

Comment: Alright, thanks I understand now, I'll get back to you if I any more issues occur.